# Is there a capability to utilize drag and drop functionality when using Ruffle?

Tags: drag-and-drop, ruffle

I've downloaded Ruffle to replace Flash functionality for my computer. I'm currently taking an online course that relies on Flash for its courses and exams. I've found that Ruffle runs the Flash programs, but any exam questions formatted as drag and drop won't work. Is there anything I can do or download to fix that capability?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily for you, I was just experimenting and playing with basic Flash examples and ruffle recently.
Check the final solution here and then I'll explain the steps:
http://www.tanadsplinare.com.hr/test5/

1. Get the bumble bee example here, all you need is SWF:

https://condor.depaul.edu/sjost/hci430/flash-examples.htm

Download bumble-bee5 ( https://condor.depaul.edu/sjost/hci430/flash-examples/swf/bumble-bee5.swf ), you just need that SWF, but anyway this site is useful if you're learning Flash

2. Download ruffle.js and corresponding.wasm file (feel free to do it from my example):

http://www.tanadsplinare.com.hr/test5/ruffle.js

http://www.tanadsplinare.com.hr/test5/aafdd926c74ff1ff1e03a02091c0405b.wasm

3. This is the HTML/JS that you run (place all files I mentioned so far in the same folder so the references won't break):

   ```
    <div id="container">
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="550" height="400">
            <param name="movie" value="bumble-bee5.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="wmode" value="window" />
        </object>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.RufflePlayer = window.RufflePlayer || {};
        window.RufflePlayer.config = {        
            "polyfills": true,
            "autoplay": "on",
            "unmuteOverlay": "hidden"
        };
    </script>
    <script src="ruffle.js"></script>
   ```

**And voila - it should work, if you run it on some web server.**
If you run it on IIS you might want to configure web.config for server to recognize .wasm mime type, put this in `<system.webServer>` node:

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
</staticContent>
```

If you wonder what the web server is, I'm afraid that you'll have to google it since it's out of scope here, but don't worry - nowadays it's easy and free to set a web server up or you can try some online.